# Large list with editable items in Android/IOS

Tags: android, ios

I have a scenario where there are around 50 - 100 items in a list. 
Each list item has 6 editable fields (Boolean, Boolean, Dropdown, Integer , Float, Float).

How can I display such a list in smartphones such that in worst case scenario if all items have to be updated (50 * 6 = 300), the number of taps should remain minimum.

for eg. if I open a new screen when user taps on a list item and updates all 6 field, and comes back to list screen,

Number of taps for each list item = { Open_Edit_Screen(1) + Boolean_values(2) + Dropdown(2) + Integer(3) + Float_values(6) + back_to_list_screen(1)} = 15

SO total taps by user = 15 * 50 = 750

Comment: Do mobile users really need the complete process to take place?

Comment: @dnbrv: Yeah unfortunately yes. And today only I came to know from a requirements Interview that the number of list items might increase up to 200 :)

Comment: That's just insane. Such a workflow is cumbersome on a large screen, and on a mobile device it'll be a torture.

Comment: Just to clarify, are we talking about phones or tablets here? Also, does a single user or multiple people carry out these actions, and all at once or over a longer period of time?

Comment: 1) Smartphone
2) Single user
3) Needs to complete task in say 20 - 30 mins or so.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't trim down the amount of data there (and that is a far more preferable choice as @Benny outlined) Add a 'Next' button on the keyboard to navigate through the fields. I've seen spotty implementations of this for email/password logins and it makes things feel much faster because you can focus on the data input and not switching fields/mis-tapping.